# How can I check if a value is a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to simply check if a returned value from a form text field is a number i.e.: 12 , 12.5 or 12.75. Is there a simple way to check this, especially if the value is pulled as a `param`?

Comment: um, the only thing is that the code works for is_a_number? works with the only exception being .02, or .3 numbers....

Comment: I much prefer this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails/5661695 I don't know why so many people think a regexp would be better for that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just regexp it, it's trivial, and not worth thinking about beyond that:

```
v =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\Z/
```

(Fixed as per Justin's comment)

Comment: In ruby, ^ and $ denote the beginning/end of a line, not of a string.  This makes this ineffective to use as a means of sanitizing inputs (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions).  A better approach would be:
`v.to_s =~ /\A[-+]?\d*\.?\d+\z/`.

Comment: This does not work for strings that represent exponential notation

`irb(main):031:0> v = "0.7e1"
=> "0.7e1"
irb(main):032:0> v =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\Z/
=> nil
`

Answer (score 242):

You can use

```
12.is_a? Numeric
```

(`Numeric` will work for integers and floats.)

If it arrives as a string that might contain a representation of a valid number, you could use

```
class String
  def valid_float?
    true if Float self rescue false
  end
end
```

and then `'12'.valid_float?` will return true if you can convert the string to a valid float (e.g. with `to_f`).

Comment: Sorry, this is Ruby on Rails ...
Basically, I just want to be able to evaluate any input from the user whether it be .03 0.3, 2.2
THe latter two work, but I need to get the first input working :S

Comment: ```Fixnum``` doesn't seem to work with floats.  However, ```Numeric``` works fine.  So ```1.234.is_a? Fixnum == false```, but ```1.234.is_a? Numeric == true```.

Comment: This doesn't work with floats.  Should use `1.1.is_a? Numeric` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668654/76486

Comment: Not working for me :(
`pry(main)> '12'.is_a? Numeric
=> false`

Comment: @Salil obviously that will not work for you, `'12'` is a String. In that case check the string with Regex or any other possible solution.

Answer (score 32):

I usually just use Integer and Float these days.

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > foo = "343"
 => "343"
1.9.2p320 :003 > goo = "fg5"
 => "fg5"

1.9.2p320 :002 > Integer(foo) rescue nil
 => 343
1.9.2p320 :004 > Integer(goo) rescue nil
 => nil

1.9.2p320 :005 > Float(foo) rescue nil
 => 343.0
1.9.2p320 :006 > Float(goo) rescue nil
 => nil
```

Comment: In ruby 2.6 you can also do the following: `Integer('343', exception: false) # 343` and `Integer('fg5', exception: false) # nil`

```

Answer (score 16):

You can add a:

```
validates_numericality_of :the_field
```

in your model.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002172

Answer (score 12):

Just convert string twice:

```
num = '12'
num == num.to_i.to_s 
#=> true 

num = '3re'
num == num.to_i.to_s 
#=> false
```

Comment: Works not so bad with integers, but there are so many ways to fail if you want to follow this advice with floats (which is what the question asks about):

`"7" == "7".to_f.to_s #=> false` ("7" vs "7.0")

Comment: You can do `num == num.to_i.to_s || num == num.to_f.to_s`

Comment: you can also format both string using the "%" operator to guarantee that they both end in the same string

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest this one

```rb
def is_a_number?(str)
  !!(Float(str) rescue false)
end

> is_a_number?(1)
 => true

> is_a_number?(1.1)
 => true 

> is_a_number?('1')
 => true 

> is_a_number?('1.1')
 => true 

> is_a_number?('a')
 => false 

> is_a_number?(nil)
 => false
```

Answer (score 4):

```
irb(main):005:0> 1.1.is_a? Numeric
=> true
irb(main):006:0> 1.is_a? Numeric
=> true
irb(main):007:0> 'asd'.is_a? Numeric
=> false
```

Comment: "1.1".is_a? Numeric

=> false

Comment: How would you tackle the String conversion problem? OP states it's from an text field.

Answer (score 1):

There was answer with `Kernel#Float`

But this variant is used with `exception: false` key and double bang to return boolean

```
class String
  def number?
    !!Float(self, exception: false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use regexp matching, for example:

```
irb(main):015:0> 12.5.to_s.match?(/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/)
=> true
```

Answer (score -6):

String values always convert to 0 with .to_i

```
[14] pry(main)> 'Apple'.to_i > 0
=> false

[15] pry(main)> '101'.to_i > 0
=> true
```

Comment: What about edge cases? If the number is 0 or negative your test will give a false negative.

Comment: Even worse '1AB2'.to_i would return 1 for something that is clearly not an Integer...

Comment: This produces the wrong answer if the string starts with a number: `1Apple`.to_i becomes `1`