# Regex to check the data entered into the field contains only numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-models

I'm using a field with string datatype, I want add validation to that field which will check if the string entered into the field contains only numbers, please help me with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check if `\D+` returns a match. If so, there's at least one element that isn't a digit.
Also, [Test if string is a number in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails#5661695) gives some answers without using regular expressions.

Comment: The above is not correct. E.g., if the pattern is like "1 2", because it will return true for white spaces also.

Comment: But that's what's expected?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below given pattern for checking:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

If it returns true, it means that there are only digits inside the field, otherwise not.