# Check if a string contains only digits in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string which is passed as a parameter to a function. Here, I want to check if the string contains only numbers. So I had a check like below:

```
def check_string(string)
  result = false
  if string.to_i.to_s.eql? string
    result =  true
  end
  result
end
```

But the problem arises when a string starts with 0. In that case, a false is returned.

```
check_string('123')  #=> true
check_string('0123') #=> false
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What should be returned if the string is empty?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails/5661695

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can try the following

```
def check_string(string)
  string.scan(/\D/).empty?
end
```

It would be truthy if string contains only digits or if it is an empty string. Otherwise returns false.

Comment: This is smart. You can also go with a variation of your answer and @Stefan's suggestion `string.scan(/^\d+$/).any?` which reads quite nicely I think.

Comment: As for me the answer as it is now is more first-look-understandable ;) Just looking for nondigit symbol. If there isn't one - check has passed.

Answer (score 6):

A number can be negative, or a float.  So if these are allowed, consider this solution:

```
def is_numberic?(str)
    str == "#{str.to_f}" || str == "#{str.to_i}"
end
```

some input which evaluate to true

```
pry(main)> is_numberic? '5'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '58127721'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '58127721.737673'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '0'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '1818'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '0.1'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '0.0'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '11.29'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '-0.12'
=> true
pry(main)> is_numberic? '-29'
=> true
```

the input which evaluate to false

```
pry(main)> is_numberic? '10 years'
=> false
pry(main)> is_numberic? '01'
=> false
pry(main)> is_numberic? '00'
=> false
pry(main)> is_numberic? '0.10'
=> false
pry(main)> is_numberic? ''
=> false
```

As you can see, there're several cases which probably should be supported, eg `'0.10'`, but are not.  In this case, the permitted input is `'0.1'`.

Answer (score 5):

```
def check_string(str)
  str !~ /\D/
end

check_string '123'
  #=> true
check_string ''
  #=> true
check_string '1a2'
  #=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

this is my proposition for detecting if it's a float number

```
def check(string)
  scan = string.scan(/\D/)
  scan.size == 0 || (scan.size == 1 && scan.first == ".") # or "," depend on your separator
end
```

example of use:

```
check("123") => true
check("12.3") => true
check("12e3") => false
check("12.3.2") => false
```

**EDIT:** 2023
After some years i see this is the most compact solution:

```
def check_string(str)
  str.scan(/\D/).empty?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regexp for it:

```
def check_string(string)
  raise 'Empty string passed' if string.empty?

  /\A\d+\z/ === string
end

check_string '123'
#=> true
check_string '0123'
#=> true
check_string '0'
#=> true
```

Comment: Wouldn't work for `string = '0'` – why not simply `/^\d+$/` or `/\A\d+\z/`?

Comment: @Stefan `/^\d+$/` makes perfect sense!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko This fails the premise for the string "foobar\n123" since your regex matches here. You actually want to use `/\A\d+\z/`.

Comment: seems this could be simplified to just `string =~ /\A\d+\z/ ? true : false` this handles all the cases and will return false on an empty string since it contains no numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the "match" function to do this.

```
"1234".match(/\D/)
#=> nil
"1234foo".match(/\D/)
#=> #<MatchData "f">
```

[match (String) - APIdock](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use the regex to find this.

```
it will work for the below scenarios
"3.0"
"av3"
"3"
```

> is_numeric = false if option.option.match?(/[^0-9.]/)

Comment: option.option is your preferred string?

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is searching for another way to determine if string is numeric -> is to use "is_a? Numeric". [Is_a? reference documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F)

```
"namaste".is_a? Numeric
=> false

6.is_a? Numeric
=> true

str1 = "foo"
str2 = 9

str1.is_a? Numeric
=> false
str2.is_a? Numeric
=> true
```

You can also use:

```
7.is_a?(Numeric)
=> true

"too".is_a?(Numeric)
=> false
```

Basically it's determining if a class is a type of class object.  I just found this and thought I would share.

Comment: Your `str2` is not a string. Try this with `str2 = "9"` and see if it works (It does not).