# Check if a string is a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to check a string entered by a user. If it is a string, then move along, if not, then throw an error. I do not know how to check if the user input is a string or an int. Below is my code:

```
puts "what is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
if name == Int
puts "error enter a string"
end
if birthdate != Int
puts "error enter your birthdate"
end
puts "how old are you "
age = gets.to_i
if age == String
puts "error please enter your age"
end

puts "hello"  + name + " wow that is a good day to be born" + "thats a great age"
puts "the half  of your age is #{age/2.0} that is good to know"
```

Comment: [Kernal#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns a string, even when it looks like some other object. For example, if `gets.chomp #=> "1"` (the user entered `"1"`), it is still a string, not an integer. Perhaps you want to know if the user has entered the string representation of a Ruby object other than a string (e.g., `"1"`, `":cat"`, `"[1,2,3]"`, `"{ :a=>1 }"`),

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails, and the 
answer by @hipertracker is what you want I think.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be checked as this:

```
  puts "what is your name?"
  name = gets.chomp
  if !(name =~ /[0-9]/).nil?
   puts "error enter a string"
  end
  puts "what is your age?"
  age = gets.chomp
  if age.to_i.to_s == age
   puts "error enter a integer"
  end
```

Comment: `age.split("").map{|val| val.to_i}.join("") == age` is overkill `age.to_i.to_s == age` would do it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
 if name.class == String
```

Also this will always be false

```
age = gets.to_i  # this is converting to integer
if age.class == String # I think this is what you meant
```

age will always be an Integer her because you have cast it as such with .to_i

Comment: Also there is_a? function in ruby.  https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F

Comment: When string value enter for age, its value will be `0` since it cast to integer.

Comment: Thank you all for the response, for the age I want it to be a number so if I type age.class == INT will it be the same as saying name,class == String ? I basically want the code to see if someone entered in  a string where it should be an int then throw an error thats why on the if statements I typed age = string and name = int so on